# SQL server - Conversion failed error but not really

Tags: sql-server-2008, split, type-conversion

I've got a user-defined function to split lists of integers into a table of values.  I'm using this to parse input to select a set of records for a given set of types or statuses.

This works:

```
select * from RequestStatus
where RequestStatusUID in (select [value] from dbo.SplitIDs('1,2,3', ','))
```

This does not:

```
select * from Requests
where RequestStatusUID in (select [value] from dbo.SplitIDs('1,2,3', ','))
```

The Requests query returns the error "**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.**" RequestStatusUID on both tables are int columns. Both Explain plans look the same to me.  The function is working perfectly the same way in unrelated queries.  So far as I can tell it's only the Requests table that has the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Requests]  ( 
[RequestUID]        int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserUID]           int NOT NULL,
[LocationUID]       int NOT NULL,
[DateOpened]        date NULL,
[DateClosed]        date NULL,
[RequestStatusUID]  int NOT NULL,
[DiscussionUID]     int NULL,
[RequestTypeUID]    int NOT NULL,
[RequestNo]         varchar(16) NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateUID]     int NOT NULL,
[LastUpdated]       date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Requests] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([RequestUID])
```

It does work if I use a different function that returns varchars and I convert the RequestStatusUID column to a varchar as well:

```
select * from Requests
where cast(RequestStatusUID as varchar(4)) in (select [value] from dbo.Split('1,2,3', ','))
```

For reference, the SplitIDs function I'm using (a modified version of [Arnold Fribble's solution](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)).  The Split function is the same without the cast as int at the end:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIDs] ( @str VARCHAR(MAX), @delim char(1)=',' )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    with cte as (
        select 0 a, 1 b
        union all
        select b, cast(charindex(@delim, @str, b) + 1 as int)
        from cte
        where b > a
    )
    select cast(substring(@str,a,
    case when b > 1 then b-a-1 else len(@str) - a + 1 end) as int) [value]      
    from cte where a >0
)
```

I can use the convert-to-strings solution but I'd really like to know why this is failing in the first place.

Comment: Also, select * from Requests where RequestStatusUID in (1,2,3) works just fine.  It's just that I need to have a variable there instead of the string literal.

Comment: I can't reproduce, even if I take out the explicit cast at the end of the function. Can you set up a complete repro on sqlfiddle.com? Also have you tried any *other* TVFs that return INTs, or are you married to this specific function? I tend to stay away from recursive CTE approaches within TVFs due to observed performance issues.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce on sqlfiddle.com it until I added the foreign key constraint... [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab4a9/1)

Comment: See? Missing information. What foreign key constraint.

Comment: To the Status table.  However, after I removed it again, the problem persists.  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10563)

Comment: My join syntax that I provided in my answer [seems to eliminate the conversion error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab4a9/4), so you can use that in the meantime.

Comment: unfortunately the status list can be null and I need to make that join optional

Comment: You know there are `OUTER JOIN`s too, right? And how are you going to make it optional with your `IN ()` syntax?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and I'm more than willing to change my functions and queries to use a more efficient structure.  I would also like to understand WHY this doesn't work and improve my understanding of how database servers function.

Comment: ... where (@statuslist is null or RequestStatusUID in (select * from dbo.SplitIDs(@statuslist, default)))

Comment: this gives the same error :select R.*
from Requests R
left outer join 
(select [value] from SplitIDs('1,2,3', default)) V
on R.RequestStatusUID = V.[value]

Comment: That left outer join won't work. Did you try it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very hard to dissect precisely why the function is failing, because it is impossible to generate a plan. I think I have provided a sufficient answer and a plan of action; if your goal is not to get a working solution but rather to understand why this specific function doesn't work for you, I'll be happy to delete my answer, but you should also re-word your question so that future answerers don't do what I did.

Comment: Yes.  It's the same issue.  I'm going to try experimenting with different split functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that this syntax performs a lot better:

```
SELECT r.* FROM dbo.Requests AS r
INNER JOIN dbo.SplitIDs('1,2,3', ',') AS s
ON r.RequestStatusUID = s.value;
```

The predicate still has a bunch of implicit converts, due to your function choice, but the join eliminates an expensive table spool. You may see even slightly better performance if you use a proper column list, limited to the actual columns you need, instead of using `SELECT *`. [You should change this even if you do need all of the columns](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Your `IN ()` query, with an expensive table spool ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umzBv.png)):

[image]

My `JOIN` version, where the cost is transferred to the scan you're doing anyway ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izhqX.png)):

[image]

And here are runtime metrics (based on a small number of rows of course) - ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Mz5.png)):

[image]

The conversion errors seem to be stemming from the function. So I substituted my own (below). Even after adding the foreign key we didn't initially know about, [I was unable to reproduce the error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4044/1). I am not sure exactly what the problem is with the original function, but all those implicit converts it creates seem to cause an issue to the optimizer at some point. So I suggest this one instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  VARCHAR(255) = ','
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT [value] = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

So, seems to me like you want to get rid of the function.

Also, here is one way to use a join and still make the param optional:

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;-- also try = '1,2,3';

SELECT r.*
FROM dbo.Requests AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(@param, default) AS s
ON r.RequestStatusUID = s.value
WHERE (r.RequestStatusUID = s.value OR @param IS NULL);
```